# Rails Group by inside Group by

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by, activemodel

I need to group my ActiveRecords first by YEAR and then by MONTH, something like this:

```
{2017=>
    "January"=>
        [Record1, record2, etc]
    "February"=>
        [Record1, record2, etc]
 2016=>
    "January"=>
        [Record1, record2, etc]
    "February"=>
        [Record1, record2, etc]
}
```

and so on...

I tried to use

```
.group_by( |a| [a.year, a.month] )
```

but the best I could get was:

```
{[2017, "January"]=>
        [Record1, record2, etc]
 [2017,"February"]=>
        [Record1, record2, etc]
 [2016, "January"]=>
        [Record1, record2, etc]
 [2016,"February"]=>
        [Record1, record2, etc]
}
```

Thanks

PS: I have column named YEAR and MONTH in my model.

PS2: I use Ruby 2.3 and Rails 4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.group_by(&:year).each_with_object({}) {|(k, v), h| h[k] = v.group_by(&:month) }
```

Will give you what you want:

```
{ 2017 => { 
    "January" => [record1, record2, etc], 
    "February" => [record1, record2, etc] 
  },
  2016 => {
...
```

So

```
results[2017]['January'] #=> [record1, record2, etc]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do nested group_by. Something like:

```
Model.group_by(:year) do |year, objects|
   objects.group_by(&:month) do |month, objects|
    //Do the actions you need for that objects
   end
end
```

Don't know if there's a more efficient way (or less verbose) to do that, but think this works. Give a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Model.all.inject({}) do |hash, record|
  hash[record.year] = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
  hash[record.year][record.month] << project
  hash
end
```